# Execute VBA Function via View Query in MS Access 2013 from JS ActiveX ADO

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, activex

How to execute a VBA macro via a view query in MS Access 2013 from JS ActiveX ADO?

The VBA function is to get the currently logged in user using:

```
Public Declare Function GetUser Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long
```

The view query is a select statement that return the VBA function value.

I want to execute that view query from JS ActiveX ADO over LAN (same domain policy). The query throws an error saying that I need at least one table or query. I also noticed that if I read from a view query that does not execute a VBA function, it passes with no problems. Is this a security control by design? Any way to get the user ID in this setup?

Thank you!

Comment: What's your query SQL? Does it run by itself in MS-Access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can't call the API function directly from a query, but if you put it in an Access module, and create a function that returns a string it should work for you.

You haven't posted any other code or SQL so I'm not sure if you've tried that yet.

Here's what I use in queries with same API sub you're using

```
Public Function NetworkUserName() As String
    Dim strBuffer As String * 255
    Dim lngBufferLength As Long
    Dim lngRet As Long
    Dim strTemp As String

    lngBufferLength = 255
    lngRet = GetUSer(strBuffer, lngBufferLength)
    NetworkUserName = Left$(strBuffer, InStr(strBuffer, Chr$(0)) - 1)
End Function
```

Then your query would just look like

```
SELECT NetworkUsername AS CurrentUser
```

**EDIT - Add possible option to use an ActiveX object inside JScript**

Instead of using ADODB call you could try pulling environmental variable `%USERNAME%` using `Wscript.Shell` ActiveX object and the `ExpandEnvironmentStrings` method.

But you're probably looking for Network username - maybe this would suffice inside JScript

```
var winNet = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Network");
alert(winNet.UserName);
```

Comment: hi. this is exactly what i have. if i run this query from ActiveX ADO connection in JS, it does not work.

Comment: all other queries that do not involve VBA functions work from this connection

Comment: Maybe update your question with an edit that includes that information.

Comment: maybe i should. thx. any suggestion on how to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't know - are you building the SQL on the fly or trying to call a prebuilt query from the MS-Access database? Do you have JS code to share?

Comment: Added Jscript option to edited answer - if that's a possible solution let me know

Answer (score 2):

Within an Access application session, a feature called the "expression service" allows the db engine to use your VBA user-defined function.  So your query runs fine from within an Access session.

However, when you attempt to run the same query via JavaScript, it is not executed within an Access application session ... so the expression service is not available to allow the db engine to use your UDF.  Therefore the query attempt fails.

And that query approach can not be made to work.  Suggest you explore the `WScript.Network` approach @dbmitch offered.

Comment: Is this expression service available from an ActiveX object?

Comment: Good background explanation of the problem. Thanks for adding that,

Comment: @geeko The expression service is a feature of the Access application.  If you have an ActiveX object within an Access session, then yes.  Otherwise no.